# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед «и» при сравнении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и, сравнительный-оборот

*А что они ожидали от тех, кто может бегать, как гепард(,) и при этом свободно стрелять из винтовки?*

Как я понимаю, в данном случае придаточные относятся к «может», поэтому запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении **одно придаточное**:

*А что они ожидали от тех, **кто может бегать, как гепард, и при этом свободно стрелять из винтовки?*** (Составное глагольное сказуемое с однородными членами, соединенными союзом: *может бегать и стрелять*.)

Если мы обособляем сравнительный оборот, то, независимо от количества придаточных и наличия общего члена, **запятые должны стоять с обеих сторон**, кроме случаев, когда «нужно показать, к какой части предложения он [сравнительный оборот] относится: *Я почувствовал на моих волосах прикосновение слабой, **как лист дрожавшей руки*** (Т.) — ‘дрожавшей, как лист’, а не ‘слабой, как лист’...» (Розенталь, [Сравнительный оборот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147), пункт 3, Примечание).

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант постановки знаков препинания:

*А что они ожидали от тех, кто **может бегать** как гепАрд и при этом свободно **стрелять** из винтОвки?*

Мне кажется важным выделить ударением **два однородных сказуемых** в составе придаточного предложения.  В этом случае сравнительный оборот является обстоятельством образа действия (= бегать очень быстро, тесно примыкает к первому сказуемому и не обособляется.

**Примечания**

1. Это СПП с придаточным местоименно-определительным, связь местоименная, местоименная пара "от тех, кто (= которые)".
2. В первом варианте другая постановка ударений: *А что они ожидали от тех, кто может **бЕгать, как гепАрд**, и при этом свободно стрелять из винтОвки?*

Ударением выделено и первое сказуемое, и обособленный сравнительный оборот. Тогда второе сказуемое приобретает **присоединительное** значение.

Поэтому здесь **авторский выбор** варианта.